# Base Class not defined?

Tags: c++, dll, interface

I have already seen a post about the error but This is some what different. So please donot close this. I have an Interface class and I have a class that inherits the interface class and overides the methods in Interface class. The code looks likes this

```
//interface file
//Interface.h
class A
{
    virtual method1();
};


//b.h 
#include "Interface.h"
class B : public A
{
     //declaration   
}

//b.cxx
#include b.h
B::method1()
{
    //definition
}
```

I am exporting all these classes in a dll. And I am using methods and classes in the dll from an exe. This exe agains contains somes classes. These classes again inherit the same interface file and also uses **method1()**. So to use **method1()** I am including b.h in my file. If order of my include statements are Interface.h and b.h, then I am getting Compiler error for exe. Telling "**base class not defined**". But if I reorder the Include statement there is no compilation error. Can any one suggest me what could be basic reason for this problem.

Comment: Can you attach the full error ? In your attempt to simply the error might have been lost

Comment: Please post the full error message and the snippet of code that actually produces the error. Otherwise we'll all just be guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two errors in your example code: First you do not declare the method without a return type, which is an error. The second is that you, at least in the snippet above, do not declare `method1` in the class definition of `B`:

```
class B : public A
{
    virtual void method1();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to declare virtual method  "method1()" in both A and B's class definition.

Comment: I have already declared it in class B. my main problem is compilation error in exe. And I am also defining method1() there in exe. But when I am compiling exe it throws me an error  that base class not defined for B.h. which should not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you interface is **IA** and is declared in **IA.h** , make sure that every class **Foo** that inherits from **IA** be it in the exe or dll includes **IA.h** before the class definition in **Foo.h**

What I suspect is happening that this is not the case and based on the header include order you might be getting the definition of **IA** in certain files and not in the others